# Append dropdown list result to formData object

Tags: php, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest, append

In html I have a file input element within a form:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select" name="photos" />
```

Then in javascript I append this to my formData object (formData) as follows:

```
formData.append('photos', file, file.name);
```

Then finally in php I retrieve the transferred file.

```
$fileName = $_FILES['photos']['name'];
```

This works great.

However I also have a dropdown list in the same form in HTML:

```
<label>Select Year to Load File to:</label>
    <SELECT name = "year_list">
        <OPTION Value="2013">2013</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="2014">2014</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="2015">2015</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="2016">2016</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
```

However it is not clear to me what the syntax I need to use to append the users selection to `formData` and also to retrieve the result in php. Can someone enlighten me as to how to do this?

***I Do not want to use jquery*.**

I understand for the append statement I should use the syntax:

```
append(DOMString name, DOMString value);
```

But then what DOMString name and DOMString value  would I use? And what would I use in `$_POST` in the php file?

Many thanks.

Comment: `DOMString name` possibly is the name of the DOM element. In your case "year_list" and `value` is the selected value for the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. After a bit of sleep and some further experimentation I got it to work as follows:

In javascript declared variables to get the values from the dropdown list and appended those values to the formData object as follows:

```
        var sel_month_list = document.getElementById("month_list");
        var month_list = sel_month_list.value;
        var sel_year_list = document.getElementById("year_list");
        var year_list = sel_year_list.value;
      formData.append('month_list', month_list);
      formData.append('year_list', year_list);
```

Then in php the following successfully retrieved the values:

```
$month = $_POST['month_list'];
$year = $_POST['year_list'];
```

Seems a little cumbersome but it worked. Feel free to pitch in if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Regards